# absolute positioned parent with a flex growing child not inheriting width

Tags: html, css, flexbox, absolute

I have a flex box that will grow column wise based on content inside it; the width of the box should fit the content. I have to place this box inside a parent container which is absolutely positioned on the page.

If I do so, the parent container is not taking the dynamic width of the child rather it's sticking to it's initial width and the child content is overflowing.

Code Available: https://jsfiddle.net/visu310p/q8hsk42L/8/

```
.parent {
  color: white;
  background: blue;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 100px;
}
.child {
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: child here will have automatic width and will grow with the flex content, so I really don't know how much it will stretch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set a `width` for the parent. That is because whenever an element is positioned absolutely the `width` and `height` is automatically set to auto. So in your case the child's `flex-wrap: wrap` will cause an overflow unless a `width` is specified for the absolutely positioned parent.

```
.parent {
  color: white;
  background: blue;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 100px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px); /* can be any value */
}
.child {
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried setting width 100% already, but for some reason it's growing beyond the child div and spanning across the page.. perhaps, I am messing up with "display" of the parent. For a flex child, should the parent be specifically of some type?

Comment: _"I tried setting width 100% already, but for some reason it's growing beyond the child"_. It's because you're pushing the parent 10px from the left (`left: 10px`). You can use something like `width: calc(100% - 20px)` to get it to work.

Comment: My actual use-case will be slightly different but yeah, I get the drift.. thank you :)